# Object goes black when decimating to reduce file size

Tags: faces, pbr

I'm trying to reduce the size of a 3D model. I tried adding the decimate modifier to all of the objects and it worked pretty well except for one.

There is a cylindrical object that goes around the couch and has about 187000 faces. When I tried decimating it, the whole object went black and it stays like that in the renders (I'm trying to render it on the web via Sketchfab).

I don't understand why a simple cylinder should need all these faces and why it goes black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the object have a material?

Comment: No, it's just the number of faces and vertices that increases the file size. Isn't there a way to turn this into a simple object without so many faces?